# IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
for i in range(1,1000):
    xplot[i]=r[0]
    yplot[i]=r[1]
    accel=fa*norm(v)*v
    accel[1]=accel[1]-g
    r=r+h*v
    v=v+h*accel
```

and ended up like this

```
---> 21     xplot[i]=r[0]
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed
```

how i fix this? help

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Show how you're initializing `xplot` and `r`

Comment: Maybe you need to reshape xplot. This looks like a vector with dimension (x,) rather than (x,y)

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `xplot.append(r[0])`

Comment: 0d arrays can only be indexed with `xplot[...]` or `r[()]` (or not all).  But you probably don't want 0d arrays.  `numpy` arrays don't grow by indexing.  `xplot` has to be big enough right from start.